# 'strsep' causing Linux kernel freeze

Tags: python, c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I have a program in userspace that writes to a sysfs file in my kernel module.
I have isolated that with high probability the source of the crash is this specific function, as when I run the user code before reaching this point it doesn't crash, but when I add the write code it crashes with high probability.
I suspect the way I parse the string causes a memory error but I don't understand why.

I am working on kernel version 3.2 and python 2.7

By crash I mean the whole system freezes up and I have to either restart it or restore the VM to a previous snapshot.

user write code(python):

```
portFile = open(realDstPath, "w")
portFile.write(str(ipToint(srcIP)) + "|" + str(srcPort) + "|")
portFile.close()
```

kernel code:

```
ssize_t requestDstAddr( struct device *dev,
                         struct device_attribute *attr,
                         const char *buff,
                         size_t count)  
{
    char *token;
    char *localBuff = kmalloc(sizeof(char) * count, GFP_ATOMIC);
    long int temp;

    if(localBuff == NULL)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR "ERROR: kmalloc failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    memcpy(localBuff, buff, count);

    spin_lock(&conntabLock);

    //parse values passed from proxy
    token = strsep(&localBuff, "|"); 
    kstrtol(token, 10, &temp);
    requestedSrcIP = htonl(temp);

    token = strsep(&localBuff, "|");
    kstrtol(token, 10, &temp);
    requestedSrcPort = htons(temp);

    spin_unlock(&conntabLock);

    kfree(localBuff);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Sure that `strsep` does not return NULL?

Comment: Why would it if I call it 2 times and have 2 pipe separators in my written string?

Comment: `In case no delimiter was found, the token is taken to be the entire string *stringp, and *stringp is made NULL.` On the next `strsep` call in case of no `|` characters in the string it will return NULL. Anyway, it's kernel, it's good to check for everything. And in that case you will call `kfree(NULL)`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely at `strsep`. From [man strsep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html):

```
char *strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim);

... and *stringp is updated to point past the token. ...
```

In your code you do:

```
char *localBuff = kmalloc(sizeof(char) * count, GFP_ATOMIC)
...
token = strsep(&localBuff, "|");
...
kfree(localBuff);
```

The `localBuff` variable is updated after the `strsep` call. So the call to `kfree` is not with the same pointer. That allows for very strange behaviors. Use a temporary pointer to save the state of `strsep` function. And check it's return value.

Comment: I saved a copy of `localBuff` and called `kfree` on it and it worked.